# Serialization troubles

Tags: java, serialization, interface, deserialization

I am still new to Java, currently studing serialization/deserialization
I have 2 classes: Hotel and Tours; interface Info. I need to do input from the keyboard about object's properties (type, other fields), then I have to create a new object with those properties and to add it to the file Data.ser

The problem is that the serialization method works; deserialization, however, doesn't. The error is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: lab1.Hotel cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
```

The following is my Main method and serialization/deserialization methods. In deserialization I use inputInfo method, which is also can be seen below.

```
class Main   {
   static ArrayList<Info> hotels = new ArrayList<Info>();
   static ArrayList<Info> tours = new ArrayList<Info>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in );
            System.out.println("Введите тип  (Tours или Hotel) ");
            String type = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Введите значение String ");
            String names= sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Введите значение Int ");
            int ints=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Введите количество элементов массива ");
            int si = sc.nextInt();
            int array[]= new int[si];
            System.out.println("Введите элементы массива ");
            for (int i = 0; i<si; i++){
                array[i]=sc.nextInt();
            }
            if(Objects.equals(type, "Hotel")==true){
                hotels = (ArrayList<Info>)deserData("hotels.ser");
                System.out.println("jjj"+hotels.size());
                Info hotel = new Hotel(names, ints, array);
                hotels.add(hotel);
                serData("hotels", hotels);
            }
            else{
                tours = (ArrayList<Info>) deserData ("tours");
                Info tour = new Tours(names,ints,array);
                tours.add(tour);
                serData("tours", tours);
            }

       }

        private static Info  deserData(String file){
            Info objs = null;
            FileInputStream fol1 = null;
            ForLab2 fl2 = new ForLab2();
            try {
                fol1 = new FileInputStream(file);
//                ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fol1);
                objs=fl2.inputInfo(fol1);
                fol1.close();
//                in.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("Ошибка1");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Ошибка2");
            }
            return objs;

        }
        private static void serData(String file, Object obj) throws IOException {
            FileOutputStream fil1 = new FileOutputStream(file +".ser");
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fil1);
            out.writeObject(obj.toString());
            fil1.close();
            out.close();
        }
    }

   static Info inputInfo(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String strLine;
        String type = null;
        String nameNew = null;
        int intNew=0;
        int[] nArr = new int[0];
        int k=0;
        Info i= new Hotel();
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null){
            if (k==0){
            type=strLine;
            k++;
        }
          else if(k==1 || k==3 || k==5){
                strLine="";
                k++;
            }
            else if (k==2){
              String result = strLine.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "");
              result= result.replaceAll(",", "");
//              String result = strLine.replaceAll("[|]|,", "");
                nArr = Arrays.stream(result.split(" ")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
              k++;
            }
            else if(k==4){
                nameNew = strLine;
                k++;
            }
            else if (k==6){
                intNew=Integer.parseInt(strLine);

            }

        }
        if(Objects.equals(type, "Hotel")==true){
            i = new Hotel(nameNew, intNew, nArr);
        }
        else{
            i=new Tours(nameNew, intNew, nArr);
        }
        return i;
   }
```

Comment: The failure is here 'hotels = (ArrayList<Info>)deserData("hotels.ser");' as you cant convert (cast) an object to a list

Comment: Hint: you compare strings like `if (type.equals("Hotel"))` ... and ideally, you might want to use type.toLowerCase().equals("hotel")) to not fail all the time on casineSs. And honestly: I have no idea what your "deser" code is supposed to do. When you write OBJECTS to an ObjectOutputStream - why on earth do you not read back Objects? It rather looks like you try to parse strings from the serialized data? Why? In other words: this is basic stuff: read and follow a tutorial that explains the required steps.

Comment: I have done this with the tutorial's help. As you can see, it didn't really help me

Comment: Could you also provide the tutorial link? As mentioned above you've mistaken the casting, you are expecting a list but your method is returning a single object type.

Comment: I can provide you with a link, but the tutoral's language isn't English
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=snw4Paafosg

Comment: Instead of doing: hotels = (ArrayList<Info>)deserData("hotels.ser"); try to cast to the appropriate type which is: hotels = (Hotel)deserData("hotels.ser"); then you would probably see the exception